# Complete Algebraic Equations

Tags: python-3.x, equation, algebra

Im trying to build an app that graphs an equation based on user input. The equation would be in slope intercept form: `y = mx + b`, for `m` as slope and `b` as `y intercept`. However, this isn't working for me in python!

I tried this:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> 1/2x
```

and was returned this:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1/2x
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

How would I make it so that this returns 1.5?

Comment: Can you ask them to input the slope and intercept separately? That would simplify the logic for pulling that data out of the equation considerably.

Comment: Technically, yes, but I wanted to make it very simple by just having them enter the equation

Comment: Why is it trying to assign <stdin> to a File type?

Comment: can user input equation with parenthesis like `(1/2)x+(3/5)` or without parenthesis `1/2x+3/5` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
mxb = re.compile('''(?P<slope>[(\d)/.]*)x\s+(?P<sign>[+-])\s+(?P<intercept>[\d./]*)''')
s = '1/2x + 5' 
match = mxb.match(s)
if match : 
    print( match.groupdict() )
```

test the python regex here : [pythex.org](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3FP%3Cslope%3E%5B(%5Cd)%2F.%5D*)x%5Cs(%3FP%3Csign%3E%5B%2B-%5D)%5Cs(%3FP%3Cintercept%3E%5B%5Cd.%2F%5D*)&test_string=x%20%2B%205%0A1%2F2x%20-%202.3%0A.5x%20%2B%201.4&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: The goal is to solve it as is. The user needs to be able to enter the equation of the line.